# Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria not working

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I'd like to disable the C# rule "Remove this cast and edit the interface to add the missing functionality" (csharpsquid:S3215). Not in general, but for all files in folders "something\Business\Genome\*.cs")
("something" can be one or more directories)

I'm trying to use the option "Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria" on this SonarQube project, but I can't figure out the correct setting (or maybe this feature is simply not working?).

Combinations I've tried so far:

```
Rule Key Pattern               File Path Pattern 
csharpsquid:S3215              **/Business/Genome/*.cs
csharpsquid:S3215              **\Business\Genome\*.cs
csharpsquid:S3215              **//Business//Genome//*.cs
*:S3215                        **/Business/Genome/*.cs
*:S3215                        **\Business\Genome\*.cs
*:S3215                        **//Business//Genome//*.cs
```

I don't even know if it's the rule key pattern or the file path pattern that is not matching... :-/

**Update 08.03.16:**
Last night I ran some additional tests. Instead of project level I configured this on global level and I used

```
Rule Key Pattern               File Path Pattern 
csharpsquid:S3215              **/?usiness/?enome/*.cs
```

to exclude casing issues: no success either.

Then I used just

```
Rule Key Pattern               File Path Pattern 
csharpsquid:S3215              **/*.cs
```

to see if it works at all, and it did. 
So somehow my path must be wrong, but I don't see how.

**Update 08.03.16 (2):** Here's one line from the log of the build server:

```
08:57:50.854 INFO  - 0/658 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Tools .Net (Nightly)\Tools\Business\Genome\Absence.cs
```

I'm pretty certain it's not a casing issue. But I have another suspicion. I scan a whole solution and apparently SonarQube treats every project in that solution as a component and scans each component/project individually. Is it possible that for the scan paths are relative to the project? Because I see also this in the log:

```
08:57:43.701 INFO  - Loading plugin stylecopanalyzers
08:57:43.924 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Tools .Net (Nightly)\Tools\Business\Genome
08:57:43.924 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Tools .Net (Nightly)\.sonarqube\out\.sonar...
08:57:44.103 INFO  - Source paths: Absence.cs, ...
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, this feature is working correctly (at least in latest versions of SQ - which version are you using?). I see that you're in a .NET shop, maybe there is some issue with the case-sensitivity of the path? Also, I assume that you've installed SQ on MS SQL DB, right? If so, then this can even get worse due to some bad collation of the table (see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements for the requirements for MS SQL).

Comment: Hi Fabrice. Casing of the folder names is correct, we're using an Oracle database, not MS SQL. We're using SonarQube 5.3.

Comment: OK, so we must miss something particular... "csharpsquid:S3215" along with "**/Business/Genome/*.cs" is the correct syntax and it should definitely work. But I'm running out of ideas. :-(

Comment: Last night I ran some additional tests. I updated the original question accordingly

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is linked to a case problem. Can you open a DOS console, "cd" into the solution and on each folder list the files in the console: this is the best way to make sure the case is correct, because Windows Explorer might fool you on this.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam I'm using Total Commander, not Windows Explorer (I don't like tools that lie to me :-) I updated my question with excerpts from scan log

Comment: Ok, you nailed it. :-) I will answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File inclusions/exclusions are based on path relative to each SonarQube module (i.e. Visual Studio project). So if "Business" is a VS project, this indeed won't work.

Comment: So there's no way to ignore this rule just for this module then?

Comment: This is a limitation indeed. This can be worked around if files of this module are located in a folder which name can be used as a discriminant. But I guess this is not the case.